# Is there a name for the date format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"?

Tags: date, naming-conventions, format

For talking over the phone or to my co-workers, is there a short-hand name for this date format already established?

Names of other standard date formats would also be useful.

Comment: I think in .NET is longdatetime format

Comment: [According to MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), it's called **ODBC canonical** (style 20/120)

Comment: +1 for ODBC canonical. The table on the page Marc linked is also a good reference to other commonly-used date standards.

Comment: we(developers) need a world without dates ;)

Answer (score 4):

That is the [ISO standard date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) and [time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times).

Comment: It could potentially be the ISO 8601 date and time separately, but only if the time is local time, not UTC time. With UTC time, a "Z" for Zulu would be appended to the time. It's more likely the OP is looking for "ODBC canonical" as @mark_s suggested above, since your answer is separate date and time formats and the OP was looking for a single format name. (See mark_s in response to Cade Roux for why ISO 8601 is not a valid answer as a combined format)

Comment: @Jon, I am referring to local time, in case that is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Not exactly - at least in SQL Server, the ISO-8601 format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` (notice the `T` separating date and time portions; CONVERT style 126 - what the OP is looking for matches stlye 20/120)

Comment: Not just in SQL Server...the actual ISO spec designates the T as required for a combined date-time format.  http://www.iso.org/iso/date_and_time_format#how-it-works