# What date-time format/standard is 2005-07-01 1:01:01?

Tags: javascript, date, time, format

I need to reproduce dates for a JavaScript app in the format `2005-11-01 1:01:01`.

- What date format is `2005-11-01 1:01:01`?
- Name for the standard (if any) that it is following?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a name for the date format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579293/is-there-a-name-for-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Comment: [Please show minimum effort](https://www.google.com/search?q=name+of+date+format+yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: According to your linked post, it is `ISO 8601`, which has a zero padded HH. So is the one in my question ISO 8601 too? Thanks for the votedown! :P

Comment: In which context/application have you come across a non-standard format like that?

Comment: I haven't come across it . I need to make it so for a specific app, so I wanted to know if there was indeed a format/standard to it, so I asked an honest question. But sorry about that. My mistake.

Comment: Turns out there isn't, so use the standard one, and display it like above using some manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on to this, this is **indeed a non-standard date format**.

The reason I'm posting this as an answer after some time, is because this format is being repeatedly given to me by at least two clients to parse and process — and they may have inadvertently supplied it to other developers, who may have similar concerns. So if any fellow devs got stumped as me, they can either 1) tell the client they have a buggy date format in store (which I did to little avail) 2) Or get this answer and correct the format ourself at our end.